# How to speed up checking and copying in ListObject

Tags: excel

I have been working with project in which the workbook crashes if too many rows of data (too many being 3000 in this case) are added.
While I have updated the workbook to now not crash at least, it is still running quite terribly slow - for adding 900 rows with only 5 columns it is taking about 33 seconds. The end table will likely have about 35 columns (of which approx 15 will be formulas) and over 5000 rows, so I am already concerned. The coworkers also wanted to be able to update using "non-matching" tables: importTable may have columns A, B, C, E and master will have A,C,E,F, and the actually needed columns (in adminTable) are A,C,E. 
Does anyone have any ideas? This subs is already wrapped in another sub that turns off screenUpdating, DisplayAlerts, and Calculation. I am guessing the hiccup is in the .Copy line...

```
Sub detectChanges(adminTbl As ListObject, importTbl As ListObject, masterTbl As ListObject)

  Dim i                           As Long
  Dim j                           As Long
  Dim elements As Long
  Dim Header As Variant
  Dim foundHeader As Variant
  Dim cHead As String
  Dim ID As Variant
  Dim foundID As Range

  elements = 0

  'loops through the set admin headers. This format will not copy non-similar data, nor overwrite custom columns that have been added to the data
 'NOTE: Below assumed that unique identifier is ALWAYS in first column.
  For i = 1 To masterTbl.ListRows.Count
    'grabs ID
    ID = masterTbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(i)
    'tests for a ID match
    Set foundID = importTbl.ListColumns(1).Range.Find(IC, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundID Is Nothing Then
        'only checks for changes in admin columns, skipping the ID column
        For j = 2 To adminTbl.ListColumns.Count
            cHead = adminTbl.ListColumns(j).Name
            If masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(i) <> 
            importTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(foundID.Row - importTbl.HeaderRowRange.Row) Then
            'This line changes the color of the changed element

                    importTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(foundID.Row - importTbl.HeaderRowRange.Row).Copy masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(i)
                    masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156)
                              'keeping track of elements
                    elements = elements + 1
            End If
        Next j

    End If

Next i

  'Say elements changed
 'MsgBox "Total elements changed in update: " & elements

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of increasing performance is by decreasing VBA's interaction with Excel objects, so it stands to reason that loops can have a large impact on performance.

Let's take a look at your three loops.

**Loop 1**

`For i = 1 To masterTbl.ListRows.Count`

This is the primary loop in your algorithm and it probably loops through the wrong table.  I both tables are the same size then it doesn't really matter; however, if the master is larger than the import (as is often the case) then you're needlessly looping through rows in the master that can't possibly exist on the import.

**Loop 2**

`importTbl.ListColumns(1).Range.Find(IC, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

Many people overlook the simple fact that `Find` is a loop and it is particularly inefficient when nested inside the `For` loop.  Consider a `For` loop that iterates through a table with 500 rows:  `Find` will be invoked 500 times and evaluate the first row a meager 500 times.  If all 500 lines contain a match then `Find` would only need to make 125,250 evaluations to find all 500.  Now hold on to your seat, if there is only one match, and it is on the 500th row, `Find` will make 249,499 evaluations before finding it on the 249,500th.  And if there are no matches?  All 500 rows will have been evaluated 500 times, a staggering 250,000 evaluations!  Let's not forget that these are all evaluations against the worksheet, the very thing you want to minimize.

**Loop 3**

`For j = 2 To adminTbl.ListColumns.Count`

This is the innermost loop and the one responsible for doing actual work.  There are several issues here that I'll break out separately.

- If the `HeaderRowRange` will not change during run time then you can avoid repeated references to `importTbl.HeaderRowRange.Row` and speed things up (albeit inperceptively) by assigning the row number to a variable above your loops.  You would then use the variable everywhere you need it.
- The cell by cell work is also slowing things down.  You have to read one cell at a time but you don't have to read every cell. Finding one change is sufficient to update the table row bail from the loop with an`Exit For`.

---

That's a lot of rambling that involves a lot of rewritten code, but that isn't what I'd actually do.  I'd go for the low hanging fruit by using a filter that reduces the size of the outter loop and eliminates `Find`.

We need an array for the filter.  This very quick short loop does fine:

```
Dim aryID() as String
ReDim aryID(1 to masterTbl.ListRows.Count)
For i = 1 To UBound(aryID)
    'grabs ID
    aryID(I) = masterTbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(i).Value2
Next i
```

We need to assign the filter and we can do that with a one liner, filters can be tricky because the current filter may be active, inactive, or absent.  So I usually pass the table to a sub to reset the filter into a known state before I set the criteria:

```
ResetTableFilters masterTbl
masterTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arryID Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

In theory, you should be able to copy and paste this in your current module and run it.  But this written on a phone and has not been tested

---

```
Sub ResetTableFilters(lo As ListObject)
    If lo.ShowAutoFilter Then lo.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter
    lo.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter                 
End Sub




Sub detectChanges(adminTbl As ListObject, importTbl As ListObject, masterTbl As ListObject)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim elements As Long
Dim Header As Variant
Dim foundHeader As Variant
Dim cHead As String
Dim ID As Variant
Dim foundID As Range

 elements = 0

 'loops through the set admin headers. This format will not copy non-similar data, nor overwrite custom columns that have been added to the data
 'NOTE: Below assumed that unique identifier is ALWAYS in first column.

Dim aryID() as String
ReDim aryID(1 to masterTbl.ListRows.Count)
For i = 1 To UBound(aryID)
    'grabs ID
    aryID(I) = masterTbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(i).Value2
Next i


For i = 1 To masterTbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

    'checks for changes in admin columns, skipping the ID column
    For j = 2 To adminTbl.ListColumns.Count
        cHead = adminTbl.ListColumns(j).Name
        If masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(i) <> 
        importTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(foundID.Row - importTbl.HeaderRowRange.Row) Then
        'This line changes the color of the changed element


          importTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(foundID.Row -   importTbl.HeaderRowRange.Row).Copy    masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(i)

              masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156)
                          'keeping track of elements
                elements = elements + 1
        End If
    Next j

End If

Next i

'Say elements changed
MsgBox "Total elements changed in update: " & elements

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ProfoundlyOblivious can you please explain a bit further about the array usage? I originally used arrays but the issue was the arrays of all the data in the import table had different columns used, plus I did not see how to keep track of the row /column combo I was working on to check. Can you please say how you would do this?

Comment: @danKing it looks like your process is relatively simple; you have a list of ID numbers and you only work with rows on a different table if they have an ID number in that list.  If this if the case, then a filter is your best performance option.  I will edit my answer to bring that into more focus.

Comment: good idea with the filter! However, I still don't see how I can write the enitre row to an array and then use this to write to the masterTbl if there are different columns in each table, with only some of them shared. Currently I need to see if the column headers match, and then if they do look at the data in that cell to see if it matches - i can't batch work all the data in the row because it would share different info. I also cannot just highlight the entire row, I have to highlight the specific cell which underwent a change.

Comment: additionally, if I were more familiar with PowerQuery I would use it but alas have never used it before

Comment: @danKing Yeah, I ran into the table comparison as I was editing my answer, i overlooked it earlier. I am still editing and believe the filter is the way to go. The comparison adds complexity and I am trying to avoid shortcuts based on assumptions that may not be true.  Such as repeated or missing ID #s, sort order, and permission to alter either table in any way other than specified - doing  this on my phone is not helping me go any faster : /

Comment: WAIT is there a way to filter the columns too? Therefore if I could do so then shouldnt I be able to batch work the rows all in one swoop? Basically: Hide the non-similar columns, put the similar columns with their rowdata into an array and work on that? As for assumption we can always assume there will be an ID, and never any duplicates. Thanks so much for you help btw!

Comment: @danKing I am not sure I follow you. Are you asking about a filter that runs down there left side of the screen, with the row numbers?  That is not coventionally possible.  But there are a thousand ways to skin this cat. A trivially easy example: add a new column to each table with a worksheet formula that concatenates fields across the row.   Each ID in each table should have the same string, any differences represents a change.  Changing the formula to an inequality with an index match to retrieve the string from the other table let's you filter changed records via True or False.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are matching ID's in the import table with the same ID in the main table. You could use a dictionary object to hold the row numbers corresponding to each ID in the main table. Build the dictionary by scanning the main table once. Then scan the import table and use the dictionary to locate the corresponding row in the main table without searching for it. For example

```vb
     Sub test()
       Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
       Set wb = ThisWorkbook
       Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

       '  tables
       Dim importTbl As ListObject, masterTbl As ListObject, adminTbl As ListObject
       Set importTbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
       Set masterTbl = ws.ListObjects(2)
       Set adminTbl = ws.ListObjects(3)

       Call detectChanges(adminTbl, importTbl, masterTbl)
     End Sub


     Sub detectChanges(adminTbl As ListObject, importTbl As ListObject, masterTbl As ListObject)

       ' build dictionary from master table
       Dim dictMaster
       Set dictMaster = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

       Dim masterRow As ListRow, ID As String
       For Each masterRow In masterTbl.ListRows
         ID = masterRow.Range.Cells(1, 1)
         dictMaster.Add ID, masterRow.index
       Next masterRow

       ' check import table against master table
       Dim importRow As ListRow, col As ListColumn
       Dim index As Long, chgCount As Long
       Dim cellMaster, cellImport As Range

       For Each importRow In importTbl.ListRows
         ID = importRow.Range.Cells(1, 1)
         If dictMaster.exists(ID) Then
           ' found - checks for changes in admin columns
           index = dictMaster(ID)
           For Each col In adminTbl.ListColumns

             cHead = col.Name
             Set cellMaster = masterTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange.Rows(index)
             Set cellImport = importTbl.ListColumns(cHead).DataBodyRange.Rows(importRow.index)
             'Debug.Print cHead, cellMaster.Address, cellImport.Address

             If cellMaster.Value <> cellImport.Value Then
                cellImport.Copy cellMaster
                cellMaster.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156)

               'keeping track of elements
               chgCount = chgCount + 1
             End If
           Next col
         Else
           ' not found - do nothing
         End If
       Next importRow

       MsgBox "Total elements changed in update: " & chgCount

     End Sub
```

Comment: Again, as with my earlier comments I don't think I can just go row by row becuase the information in row in one table will not be the same as in the destination table. While they may share some similar columns they will not share all similar columns. So there will be some false positives for changes with your above code.

Comment: @danKing1 The comparison is done only on the 'admin columns' which I thought were the ones common to both master and import. Sorry if I have misunderstood.